# Using R to Scrape discogs

Tags: r, httr, discogs-api

I use the following in my attempt to get a list of album release from Hank Mobley, a Blue Note jazz musician:

```
library(magrittr);library(httr)
releasesHM<-httr::GET("https://api.discogs.com/artists/135872/releases")
```

This result is error free and I get 15k of data, but I can't seem to identify the content in the 10-item list that results:

```
Response [https://api.discogs.com/artists/135872/releases]
  Date: 2019-01-09 14:19
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: application/json
  Size: 15.7 kB
```

[discogs says](https://www.discogs.com/developers/#page:database,header:database-artist-releases) I should have the title and year of each release from this artist.  Can anyone offer a solution/guidance?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output is in JSON, so use package jsonlite to import it:

```
library(jsonlite)
releasesHM <- fromJSON("https://api.discogs.com/artists/135872/releases")
```

You'll get a list with the data.

Titles:

```
> head(releasesHM$releases$title)
[1] "The Max Roach Quartet Featuring Hank Mobley"
[2] "Mobley's Message"                           
[3] "Jazz Message #2"                            
[4] "The Jazz Message Of"                        
[5] "Base On Balls / Stella-Wise"                
[6] "Lower Stratosphere / Reunion"
```

Artists:

```
> head(releasesHM$releases$artist)
[1] "The Max Roach Quartet* Featuring Hank Mobley"                                                                      
[2] "Hank Mobley"                                                                                                       
[3] "Hank Mobley"                                                                                                       
[4] "Donald Byrd, Hank Mobley, Horace Silver, Doug Watkins, John La Porta*, Ronnie Ball, Wendell Marshall, Kenny Clarke"
[5] "Hank Mobley"                                                                                                       
[6] "Hank Mobley"
```

Comment: Hey, great!  Thank you!

Comment: @RSchifini  Why doesn't this work, however?  `HMcaddy <- fromJSON("https://api.discogs.com/masters/239711/")`

Comment: Maybe because it lacks "releases" at the end?